# How to add the value of level with the same email in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query

```
SELECT `email`, `score`, `score` * 100 / t.s AS `Grade Percentage %` 
FROM `rank` 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(`level`) AS s FROM `history`) t
GROUP BY `email`
```

**rank Table:**

[image: here is my database of Rank]

**history Table:**

[image: here is my database of History]

my desired output for example with kemp score after multiplying the score of kemp by 100, i want to divide it with the total of his level which is 4. help me i cant seem to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You could also use only `subquery` instead

```
SELECT r.email,  r.score, 
       (r.score * 100 / (SELECT SUM(level) 
                         FROM history 
                         WHERE email = r.email)) AS `Grade Percentage %` 
FROM rank r;
```

However, this assumes always `rank` table has only one copy of `email`, else you would need to use `GROUP BY`

**Edit :**

```
update rank r
set r.`Grade Percentage %` = (r.score * 100 / (SELECT SUM(level) 
                                               FROM history 
                                               WHERE email = r.email));
```

Comment: there is only one rank so there is no problem.

Comment: what if i want to put the result in a table column `Grade Percentage %`

Comment: for example? i'm really new at sql and still learning. I have no idea on how to do it although i'm thankful for your help.

Comment: in the percentage query that's where i put the Select part?

Answer (score 0):

Use sub query with `GROUP BY` in the join as below

```
SELECT r.email, 
    r.score, 
    (r.score * 100 / t.lvl) AS `Grade Percentage %` 
FROM `rank` r 
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                email, SUM(`level`) lvl 
            FROM `history` GROUP BY email) t ON t.email = r.email
```

To store result in the column `Grade Percentage %` of `rank` table

```
UPDATE `rank` r 
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                email, SUM(`level`) lvl 
            FROM `history` GROUP BY email) t ON t.email = r.email
SET `Grade Percentage %` = (r.score * 100 / t.lvl)
```

Comment: what if i want to put the result in a table column Grade Percentage % in the Table Rank